# Binding Blob type from ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, xmlhttprequest, blob

I've developed an API for validating Excel files and displaying the code content within it. My goal is to call this API using Ajax on the client-side. However, I've encountered an issue with the **`blob`** type **`xhrcontent`**, which seems to be causing confusion. To help clarify, I'm providing an overview of the relevant code snippets:

- Here is the API

```
@PostMapping("/valid-excel")
public ResponseEntity<Object> validateExcel(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    try (InputStream is = file.getInputStream()) {
            
     /* code handle read and write excel file etc..
      * inside a count variable for counting error
      * if count > 0 mean error exist and give out file for client can download 
      * else if count == 0 mean notifying client that their file good has no err
      * if the system has interval error, fire swal popup for them 
      */

      if (count != 0) {
          ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          workbook.write(outputStream);

          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
          String fileName = "IMPORT_FILE_" + file.getName() + "_validate.xlsx";
          headers.setContentDispositionFormData(fileName, fileName);
          return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(outputStream.toByteArray());
      } else {
          return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new ResponseDto(true, Message.SUCCESS_VALID_EXCEL.value()));
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.internalServerError().body(new ResponseDto(false, Message.ERROR_INTERVAL_SERVER.value()));
    }
}
```

- Here is the ajax at client-side

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/valid-excel',
    type: 'POST',
    data: file,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status != true || response.status == undefined ){
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            var blob = new Blob([response.body], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
            var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
            downloadLink.href = url;
            downloadLink.download = 'VALIDATED_EXCEL_FILE.xlsx';
            downloadLink.textContent = 'Download Validated Excel File';
            $('#fileInput').after(downloadLink);
         } else {
             Swal.fire({
                 icon: 'success',
                 title: 'Success',
                 text: response.data,
             });
         }       
     },
     error: function (error) {
         console.log({error})
         Swal.fire({
             icon: 'error',
             title: 'Error',
             text: 'An error occurred while processing the file.',
         });
     }
});
```

Although this approach works, the file isn't functioning correctly. When attempting to open the file, an error message is displayed:

`"Excel cannot open the file because the format is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."`

I suspect that the error might be occurring during the conversion of the byte stream to a file using the **`blob`** approach.

Can anyone help me fix this for the type Blob in Ajax side, I tested my API on Postman and I'm sure myself that the file has err (count >0) of response (open success and show what i want) and the file has no err mean response (count==0) already be the result as expected. Any support will be valueable to me, **Appreciate** your time and help!

- I try to add this option on the Ajax request setup, then the file works well, but when variable `count` has no error ( mean count == 0 ), the response `ResponseDto` to transfer data to the popup does not work and Ajax throws the error case for `responseText` inside after `console.log(error)` is `[object Blob]`

  ```
  xhrFields: {
     responseType: 'blob'
  },
  ```
- Then with the same option above, I tried add this `xhr.responseType = '';` if `response.isOk == true` inside success area, but it seem meaningless